# Making a block wait in a serial queue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, grand-central-dispatch, event-dispatch-thread

I am using a serial queue in GCD like

```
dispatch_queue_t myCustomQueue;
myCustomQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyCustomQueue", NULL);

dispatch_async(myCustomQueue, ^{
    ....
/* some asyncronus call*/

});
```

in the block i want to make a asynchronous call like playing a audio,

My main problem is as soon as i am making a asynchronous call the block is not waiting and it completes the execution of whole block.

Can i make the block wait for some time until some callback from the asynchronous call returns

Comment: Do you get a callback when async call is done? In that case you can use completion handlers via GCD.

Comment: @PraveenS If i am not wrong my completion Handler will execute in the thread in which audio is playing..But i want to execute the callback method in the same thread as the serial queue..Actually all the serial queue are part of a group dispatch

Answer (score 0):

The *block* cannot wait, but the *thread* who is exceuting it can.

Look into [NSCondition](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/Reference/Reference.html) which enables you to `wait` and `signal` threads

Basically you allocate a `NSCondition` and in the block you'll have `[condition wait];` which will cause the thread to wait.
then, when the async operation is done, you call `[condition signal];` which will signal the waiting thread to continue.